# Action is being dispatched before the api call so payload is being send as promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import {fetchData} from "../common/helpers";
import {updateData} from "../Data/ducks/actions"
```

fetchData will check for is data available in local storage or not otherwise it will make an api call to get the data.

```
class Data {
  dataCheck(id) {

    if (isDataAvailable) {
      let data;
      const fetchEligibleData = async () => {
        let dataAvailabilityCheck = fetchData("DATA_EMPLOYEE");
        data = dataAvailabilityCheck;
        if (dataAvailabilityCheck instanceof Promise) {
          data = await dataAvailabilityCheck;
        }
        return data;
      }

      const eligibleData = fetchEligibleData();
      Store.dispatch(updateData({ availableData: eligibleData }))
    }
  }
}

export default new Data
```

in the above code the important part starts from if(isDataAvailable).

payload for the updateData action is always being sent as promise. this is not expected behaviour.
first promise should be resolved then the data will be passed to the updateData action.
Please suggest me the approach to solve the promise before store action being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Set variable data to the result of the promise if it is successful. I.E. `fetch(APIURL).then(res => data = res);`
Or, `fetch(APIURL).then(async res => data = await res.JSON());`

I realized your api call is elsewhere, and it looks like you're querying it for specific 'Employee' info. Without seeing that, I'm not sure what you're doing there. I don't know that you should be awaiting a promise at that point, but if you are, you still will need to get the result of it.